# java gc: what programming style makes safe point attainment easier (faster)?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose I want help garbage collector.
One of ways to spend less time in GC is to reach safepoints faster.

Before a GC can be started, all threads must be parked at safepoints.

Safepoint is a "special place" in execution flow, where thread can be safely stopped to perform GC.

I want to minimize time of waiting of safe points in my code.
What coding style will help me to reach safepoints faster?

What style makes this task more uncomfortable?

Under *style* I mean everything in language, that helps (or prevents) quick "acquisition" of safepoint.

Examples:

Is disk IO work making it more problematic?

Is JNI making it more problematic?

Is Thread.sleep() making it more hard?

Is synchronized(..) making it harder?

etc..

In short, what java operations and methods will make quick "acquisition" of safepoint problematic? And what helps?

Comment: hey, unhold my question.

Comment: Have you actually observed any problem with the GC that needs fixing? Avoiding premature optimizations and all that.

Comment: I'm not asking how to fix problems. There are no problems.
I'm asking how to program (write code, design) in order to allow GC spend less time in waiting for safepoint.

Comment: Ok, put differently, what makes you think that this is necessary in practice?

Comment: This question is actually rather unrelated to GC (which needs safepoints, but so do e.g. class loading or (AFAIK) deoptimizations). There are (udes to be?) some bugs in the JVM making reaching a savepoint take too long.  It's also a trade-off between wasting time in frequent checks and wasting time with all but one threads waiting for the one reaching the savepoint last. There might be JVM option for this, but I doubt you should/can do anything via your coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with this comment (from "src/hotspot/share/runtime/safepoint.cpp" file in the OpenJDK source):

```
  // Java threads can be in several different states and are
  // stopped by different mechanisms:
  //
  //  1. Running interpreted
  //     The interpreter dispatch table is changed to force it to
  //     check for a safepoint condition between bytecodes.
  //  2. Running in native code
  //     When returning from the native code, a Java thread must check
  //     the safepoint _state to see if we must block.  If the
  //     VM thread sees a Java thread in native, it does
  //     not wait for this thread to block.  The order of the memory
  //     writes and reads of both the safepoint state and the Java
  //     threads state is critical.  In order to guarantee that the
  //     memory writes are serialized with respect to each other,
  //     the VM thread issues a memory barrier instruction
  //     (on MP systems).  In order to avoid the overhead of issuing
  //     a memory barrier for each Java thread making native calls, each Java
  //     thread performs a write to a single memory page after changing
  //     the thread state.  The VM thread performs a sequence of
  //     mprotect OS calls which forces all previous writes from all
  //     Java threads to be serialized.  This is done in the
  //     os::serialize_thread_states() call.  This has proven to be
  //     much more efficient than executing a membar instruction
  //     on every call to native code.
  //  3. Running compiled Code
  //     Compiled code reads a global (Safepoint Polling) page that
  //     is set to fault if we are trying to get to a safepoint.
  //  4. Blocked
  //     A thread which is blocked will not be allowed to return from the
  //     block condition until the safepoint operation is complete.
  //  5. In VM or Transitioning between states
  //     If a Java thread is currently running in the VM or transitioning
  //     between states, the safepointing code will wait for the thread to
  //     block itself when it attempts transitions to a new state.
  //
```

From this I conclude the following:

- When a JVM thread is *interpreting* bytecodes, it can reach a safepoint following any bytecode.
- When a JVM thread is running code that has been JIT compiled, the behavior depends on when / where the JIT compile injects instructions to poll the "Safepoint Polling" page.
- When a native (JNI) thread is running, it is ignored from the perspective of safepoints.  However, I believe that some JNI calls will cause the native thread to block if a safepoint is underway.
- If a Java thread is blocked (e.g. by the thread scheduler or by an I/O syscall) or if it changes state, a safepoint can proceed.

But this only goes part way to answer the question.  The problem is that safepoint polling in JIT compiled code is done by instructions added by the JIT compiler.  The logic that controls this is not specified<sup>1</sup>, and is liable to be implementation dependent.  Furthermore, I have heard that memory copying using `System.arraycopy` and other built-in / intrinsic operations *may* go a long time without a safepoint check.

Concerning your specific examples:

> Is disk IO work making it more problematic?

Explicit I/O (e.g. via `read` and `write` calls) is not problematic.  Memory mapped file I/O can be a problematic; see below.

> Is JNI making it more problematic?

No.

> Is `Thread.sleep()` making it more hard?

No.

> Is `synchronized(..)` making it harder?

No.

And for your general question:

> What style makes this task [*of reaching safepoints*] more uncomfortable?

1. Avoid long counted loops.
2. Avoid things that will generate lots of virtual memory page misses.

The page miss issue is that when application code tries to read or write a virtual memory page that is not currently in RAM, the OS has to read it from disk.  This happens transparently to the application ... but the thread that was trying to access the page is blocked while this happens.  It won't be able to reach the next safepoint while this is going on.

Things that are liable to lead to an unhealthy number of page misses are:

- running a JVM with a large heap or off-heap memory usage on a machine with insufficient RAM, or
- using large memory mapped files, especially if they are larger than the available RAM.

This effect will be exacerbated if the disk device is slower.

---

<sup>1 - According to [this source](https://medium.com/software-under-the-hood/under-the-hood-java-peak-safepoints-dd45af07d766), a poll is inserted on a backwards branch in a non-counted loop and on either method entry or exit.  This is platform dependent</sup>

Comment: Disk I/O can _absolutely_ cause safepoint issues if it is using memory mapped files.   Any large allocation of native memory with direct buffers, or access of direct memory, can lead to the OS paging to or from disk (even without a swap file if there are memory mapped files), and cause safepoint issues.   From the JVM's perspective, accessing native memory is just an OS memory reference -- but the OS has other ideas, and that could either force a page flush, or a read, or swap activity, all which will induce safepoint delays.